# Sorting numerically by columns that share the same delimiter character

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sorting

I have the following content in my file:

```
172.16.0.3  3.2.10  User exists
172.16.0.2  1.1.11  User don't exist
172.16.0.4  4.1.1   User exists
172.16.0.4  4.1.13  User exists
172.16.0.3  3.5.4   User exists
172.16.0.2  3.1.15  User exists
```

I would like to sort it by the first column, then the second column in numerical order. I am aware of the `sort` command and its `-k` and `-t` options. However, as both column 1 & 2 has the same delimiter `.` I am not sure how to achieve my goal.

The way I anticipated `sort -n -t . -k 1,1 -k 2,2` would generate (note the sorting was not done correctly for `172.16.0.4` as `4.1.1` should come before `4.1.13`):

```
172.16.0.2  1.1.11  User don't exist
172.16.0.2  3.1.15  User exists
172.16.0.3  3.2.10  User exists
172.16.0.3  3.5.4   User exists
172.16.0.4  4.1.13  User exists
172.16.0.4  4.1.1   User exists
```

The desired output should be like below:

```
172.16.0.2  1.1.11  User don't exist
172.16.0.2  3.1.15  User exists
172.16.0.3  3.2.10  User exists
172.16.0.3  3.5.4   User exists
172.16.0.4  4.1.1   User exists
172.16.0.4  4.1.13  User exists
```

How can I achieve this please?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52762/trying-to-sort-on-two-fields-second-then-first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU sort: `sort -V file`

> `-V`: natural sort of (version) numbers within text

Output:

```
172.16.0.2  3.1.15  User exists
172.16.0.3  3.2.10  User exists
172.16.0.3  3.5.4   User exists
172.16.0.4  4.1.1   User exists
172.16.0.4  4.1.13  User exists
```

Comment: This works for me, cheers Cyrus! I can't believe it was this easy, silly me. :P